# How to read remote INI files

Tags: c, windows, winapi, filesystems, ini

I read INI file strings through GetPrivateProfileString API. However, the INIs in local windows directory could be read like that.
How can I read and edit a INI file in a Remote machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you're asking how to read a remote file (which is what this would boil down to).  The easiest option if it's available is probably to just read the file using a remote UNC file path, e.g. `\\SomeMachine\SomeShare\TheFile.ini`.  If you can't do that, you need to figure out a way to transfer the file to the local machine, either out of band or on demand using named pipes, TCP sockets, or something similar.

Why are you using INI files anyway? They were essentially deprecated after the 16-bit Windows era.  I'd highly recommend a different approach (e.g. the registry, an XML config file, ...).

Comment: GetPrivateProfile string automatically parses INI and fetches the string if I pass a setting name.  It just takes the filename and not the path, instead it searches the windows directory for that file. If it takes a full path i would have given remote UNC path.

Comment: It turned out the Registry wasn't quite the silver bullet solution everyone thought it would be. Applications dumping strictly private configuration settings into a giant public database isn't necessarily the best idea ever conceived. Certainly an XML file might be a better solution than INI files, but don't be so quick to reject the use of INIs categorically just because they sound like "old technology" to you.

Comment: @Beetles: Yes, it *can* do that. But you can also specify a path name in the `lpFileName` parameter. [Check the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724353.aspx) for more details.

Comment: @Cody Inifiles may still be useful in localised scenarios, but private profile string API was deprecated a loooong time ago.

Comment: @Cody yes, i have to edit INI in other domain, so i use logonuser api to acces the file. Lemme try. thanks for your help.

Comment: @David I have to edit GPO info in Sysvol for my product. Some of the GPO settings are as INI files. To work on windows layer, I still have to work with ini files.

Answer (score 3):

You should not expect to be able to modify INI files stored on remote machines. Whatever your problem is, this is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I only found out recently that you can't access INI files on UNC paths.

My solution was to map a drive letter to that location and it worked.

So instead of 
\myserver\myinipath\myinifile.ini

I mapped X to that location...........

net use x: \myserver\myinipath

in case you need to login to that UNC path/server then

net use x: \myserver\myinipath /user:loginname password

I now use x:\myinifile.ini